# Can i remove postal code input box in the shopify?

Tags: web, shopify, shopify-app, shopify-template

I want to remove postal code input box from the shipping address.
[Shipping Address form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FEkYl.png)

I have tried a lot of things like adding CSS in the theme.liquid file and tried to change the settings from check out and account settings but i am unable to figure this out.

Comment: Show us the contents of the theme.liquid file. It's very possible you can't remove this, though. Shopify probably needs it to process many cards.

Comment: Update: Looks like you can't. https://community.shopify.com/c/technical-q-a/remove-zipcode-post-code-in-checkout-page/td-p/475294 "When it comes to the checkout page in your Shopify store it is, unfortunately, unable to be adjusted as it needs to meet the requirements for processing the credit cards. The coding to that is locked so you won't be able to adjust it, our team won't be able to make customizations for you and neither will the Shopify Experts."

Comment: why would you want to remove it? So any packages to be shipped cannot be reliably delivered? Or is it because the people that will every use this store, live in a place where this is no such thing as postal code, and therefore it is a useless field?